# Updating UIImage within arrayed UIImageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I can now display a UIImageView that is within an array but using the following:

```
[[self.guess objectAtIndex:1] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:[self.guess objectAtIndex:1]];
```

If I want to change the image within one of my UIImageViews within the array
I can use:

```
[self.guess replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:Square];
```

but I then have to remove the original view, then add the new subview again:

```
[[self.guess objectAtIndex:1] removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:[self.guess objectAtIndex:1]];
```

The trouble is, my new subview does not inherit the frame position and size
of the original image (as this may have changed). Is there a way to do this 
more easily?

I was hoping for something like this, that would just update the original 
image in the same position, with the same size:

```
[self.guess.image replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:Square.image];
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to store only the images in the array and just have one UIImageView? Then, just replace the image inside the UIImageView element

Answer (score 1):

What Radu already said, its better to keep an array of images, or imageNames. Then you also do not have to remove the imageView from the superView, you just reuse the one and only one ImageView.

So what you left is something like this

```
yourImageView.image = [self.guess objectAtIndex:1];
```

And if you only store the names in the array

```
yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.guess objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't if you've tried this yet, but this should work.

```
UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[self.guess objectAtIndex:1];
img.image = Your Image;
```

Comment: I could have one view and store the images in an array, but I'd then have to rewrite lots of code. I tried a variation of Brandons answer:UIImageView *test=[self.guess objectAtIndex:1];
    self.Square.frame=test.frame; and this seems to get round my problem, although its still long winded!Thanks!